# How to modify an array subset in Ruby iteratively?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, iterator

I know the idiomatic way to do a `for` loop in Ruby is to use an Enumerator like `.each`, but I'm running into a problem: I'd like to iterate over a subset of an Array and modify those elements. Calling `.map!` with a subset like `ary[0..2]` or `.slice(0..2)` doesn't seem to do it; presumably because that slicing operator is creating a new Array?

Desired behavior with `for` instead of iterator:

```
iter_ind = [2,3,4]
my_ary = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
for j in iter_ind
  my_ary[j] = my_ary[j] + 1
  # some other stuff like an exchange operation maybe
end
=> [1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11]
```

Things that don't work:

```
irb(main):032:0> ar[2..4].map! {|el| el = el+1}
=> [6, 8, 10]
irb(main):033:0> ar
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
irb(main):034:0> ar.slice(2..4).map! {|el| el = el+1}
=> [6, 8, 10]
irb(main):035:0> ar
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
irb(main):036:0> ar[2..4].collect! {|el| el = el+1}
=> [6, 8, 10]
irb(main):037:0> ar
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Comment: thanks for the edit, I must've accidentally clicked that suggested tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *may* also try the following:

```
?> ary = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]

?> ary.map!.with_index {|item, index| index.between?(2, 4) ? item += 1 : item}
=> [1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11]

?> ary
=> [1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

In example below I implemented something that could be named `map_with_index`. `each_with_index` if no block given returns iterator. I use it to map our array.

```
ary = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]   
ary.each_with_index.map { |elem, index| index.between?(2, 4) ? elem += 1 : elem } 
# => [1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#each_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index) if you don't mind referencing the array twice:

```
ary = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
ary.each_index { |i| ary[i] += 1 if i.between? 2, 4 }
#=> [1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11]
```

Or if you don't want to iterate the whole array, this would work, too:

```
ary = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
ary[2..4] = ary[2..4].map { |el| el + 1 }
ary
#=> [1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11]
```

Comment: Does the multiple referencing have a significant effect on speed?

Comment: It should be faster in this case.